# How to align all fields regardless of width

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want all my fields to be aligned like in this first image, even if the label for the input is shorter. You can see that all the input boxes are aligned on the right hand side in the image you're looking at. I don't want to specify margins for each input as there will be 88 input fields by the end of this.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

.locate__dropdown {
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.7em;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.locate__open {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

#locateForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  height: 2em;
  width: 12em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}
```

```html
<section id="locate">
  <div class="locate__dropdown">
    <img src="down-arrow.png" alt="">Locate
  </div>

  <div class="locate__open">
    <form action="#" id="locateForm">
      <label>
          Locate Ticket #
          <input type="text" name="ticketNum" id="ticketNum">
        </label>

      <label>Predecessor
          <input type="text" name="predecessor" id="predecessor">
        </label>

      <label>
          Ticket Status
          <select id="ticketStatus" name="ticketStatus">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="correction">Correction</option>
            <option value="original">Original</option>
            <option value="relocate">Relocate</option>
            <option value="update">Update</option>
          </select>
        </label>

    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Desired UI:

[image: Desired UI]

How mine is appearing:

[image: my UI]

Comment: Separate your `label`s from the elements they label (and give the `for` attributes accordingly) then set a common width to all of them.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Set a common width to labels or fields? Or both?

Comment: Whatever you want a common width on. You asked about labels, so that's what I would suggest...

Comment: @HereticMonkey the common width is fine, I can do that but I want them all to be aligned at the same place on the right hand side in the first image. Some will have to be much smaller, so they can't all have common widths

Comment: Of course they can. The `label` element is wider than the text it contains. You just set it to have `text-align: right; width: 300px;` and the ones without much text will be aligned to the right with a bunch of whitespace on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go.
You will have to update your HTML and CSS according to the snipped I created below.

Styles go directly on the `label` and on the `input` and `select`, so the amount of fields doesn't bother at all. I made some more adjustments to the CSS maked with *new* or *changed*

In the HTML The label does not contain the form element, instead, it's placed above the form element and references the ´id´ of the respective form element with the `for` attribute. So they are siblings now, not decendants.

PS: there is no "best" way. If it's resilient and works, it's good. no matter if you use flexbox, grid or float.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.locate__dropdown {
  margin-top: 3em;
  margin-left: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.7em;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.locate__open {
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

#locateForm {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* <-- changed */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* <-- new */
  justify-content: center;
  width: 70%; /* <-- new */
}

label { /* <-- new */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 35%;
}

input, select { /* <-- new */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 65%;
}
```

```html
<section id="locate">
    <div class="locate__dropdown">
      <img src="down-arrow.png" alt="">Locate
    </div>

    <div class="locate__open">
      <form action="#" id="locateForm">
        <label for="ticketNum">Locate Ticket #</label>
        <input type="text" name="ticketNum" id="ticketNum">

        <label for="predecessor">Predecessor</label>
        <input type="text" name="predecessor" id="predecessor">

        <label for="ticketStatus">Ticket Status</label>
        <select id="ticketStatus" name="ticketStatus">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="correction">Correction</option>
          <option value="original">Original</option>
          <option value="relocate">Relocate</option>
          <option value="update">Update</option>
        </select>

      </form>
    </div>
 </section>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I wanted, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This may be accomplished in a variety of ways. The "best" way to do this now would likely be to use CSS grids.

```css
.grid-container{
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 1px solid black;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto; /* two columns auto defined width */
}

.grid-container > div:nth-child(even) { 
background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-container > div:nth-child(odd) { 
background-color: blue;
text-align: right;
color: white;
}

.grid-container div.weird-one{
width: 400px; 
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
<div>label</div>
<div>input</div>
<div>label</div>
<div class="weird-one">input</div>
<div>label</div>
<div>input</div>
</div>
```

For more information see:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid
- https://cssgridgarden.com/

Comment: In the future, just use the snippet's "Copy snippet to answer" button to copy the snippet from the question to your answer so that the user can see the CSS working on their HTML. As it is, they'll have to deconstruct your code and fit it back to theirs.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. Do you know how to do inline "code styling?" Something like the equivalent to ctrl+m in JIRA?

Comment: Not sure what that is. The snippet has a Tidy button that will indent things for you...

Comment: Okay, thanks. Cheers.

Comment: ctrl+m in JIRA makes this to `this`. you can accomplish that with the ` character wrapping it around the desired words

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @jessman5